# TextView does not display < symbol

Tags: android, textview

TextView does not display the `<` symbol.

How can I make it so it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML Encoding**

Try htmlEncode() from android.text.TextUtils

```
TextUtils.htmlEncode("My String with <");
```

**HTMLDecoding**

To decode HTML encoded Strings use fromHtml(htmlEncodedString) from android.text.Html

```
Html.fromHtml(htmlEncodedString).toString();
```

**[EDIT]**
You asked how you must proceed after retrieving the TextView by its ID from the resource XML. You would set its text like that:

```
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
t.setText(TextUtils.htmlEncode("My HTML encoded String with <"));
```

Don't forget to `import android.text.TextUtils` first!

Comment: Hi, where do i use the text view id.

Comment: @Sudanshu: What do you mean? Do you want to set the text of the TextView by code or in a layout XML file? If you want to set the text in a XML file try to escape "<" by writing \\< ...

Comment: @das_weezuli i actually wanted to try both

and i wrote android:text="\\<"

Comment: @Sudanshu: Updated my answer. Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML entity `&lt;`.

Comment: hi,Sorry could you explain in the following scenario TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
now what do i do after finiding the id.